# Spring-Integration webflux: equivalent of attribute message-converters for a webflux inbound-endpoint

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, declarative

I'm attempting a migration from `int-http:inbound-gateway` version MVC to `int-webflux:inbound-gateway` version webflux.  I'm stuck on the equivalent of the attribute `message-converters` in the MVC version for webflux.  I have converters that are invoked in the MVC side for the return body from the inbound-gateway.  Is there no body conversion for inbound-gateway in webflux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `codec-configurer` is some level of equivalent:

```
    <xsd:attribute name="codec-configurer" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:appinfo>
                <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                    <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer"/>
                </tool:annotation>
            </xsd:appinfo>
            <xsd:documentation>
                A 'ServerCodecConfigurer' for the request readers and response writers.
                By default the 'ServerCodecConfigurer#create()' factory is used.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

The WebFlux does not use a `HttpMessageConverter` abstraction, rather it uses an `HttpMessageReader` and `HttpMessageWriter` pairs.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/webflux.html#webflux-inbound

> You can configure the `WebFluxInboundEndpoint` with a custom `ServerCodecConfigurer`, a `RequestedContentTypeResolver`, and even a `ReactiveAdapterRegistry`.

Comment: I've gone with the ```HttpMessage{Reader,Writer}``` mechanism and this is working well.  Of course, that gives rise to at least one other question that I will add separately.  Thanks very much for this guidance.