# How to add HttpMessageWriter<> to webflux outbound-gateway

Tags: xml, spring-integration, spring-webflux, reactive, declarative

Thanks for the pointers for adding the `codec-configurer` attribute to a `webflux:inbound-gateway` component.  [answer to previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74350798/16750357)

That works pretty well.

I was expecting something similar for the `webflux:outbound-gateway` component but I haven't been able to find the equivalent of `codec-configurer` for that component, nor for the component used in the `web-client` attribute.  Would there be an example of such a thing?  Or, perhaps, instead, is there a way of adding my custom `codec-configurer` to the default list, hence obviating the additional `codec-configurer`?

Thanks for any new pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That configuration is a part of the `WebClient` you can inject to this gateway.
See its builder:

```
    /**
     * Configure the codecs for the {@code WebClient} in the
     * {@link #exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies) underlying}
     * {@code ExchangeStrategies}.
     * @param configurer the configurer to apply
     * @since 5.1.13
     */
    Builder codecs(Consumer<ClientCodecConfigurer> configurer);
```

And docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder

Essentially this is the code you need to follow:

```
           WebClient.builder()
                    .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer
                            .customCodecs()
                            .register())
```