# Spring Webflux Codec: Can a custom codec be added the the list of default codecs globally?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-webflux, reactive, codec

I've been shown how to add custom Codecs to `webflux:inbound-gateway` and `webflux:outbound-gateway` declarations using respectively the `codec-configurer` and `web-client` attributes. [How to add HttpMessageWriter<> to webflux outbound-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74377369/how-to-add-httpmessagewriter-to-webflux-outbound-gateway/74378627#74378627)

Is there a way (and perhaps even a simple way) of adding one's custom codec to the list of default codecs and hence avoid having to declare these in the endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `CodecConfigurerFactory`. You can use a `CodecConfigurer.properties` file to specify your custom strategies for those codecs:

```
# Default CodecConfigurer implementation classes for static Client/ServerCodecConfigurer.create() calls.
# Not meant to be customized by application developers; simply instantiate custom impl classes instead.

org.springframework.http.codec.ClientCodecConfigurer=org.springframework.http.codec.support.DefaultClientCodecConfigurer
org.springframework.http.codec.ServerCodecConfigurer=org.springframework.http.codec.support.DefaultServerCodecConfigurer
```